# Change string using sed with specific condition

Tags: bash, sed

I want to change paths in files using sed.
Now I run following :

```bash
find . -type f | xargs sed -r -i "s/home\/some_dir/home\/another_dir/g"
```

But I want this to be applied only for those paths, which correspond actual files in my file system.
For instance : if I don't have file `home/some_dir/lol`, then corresponding string in some file will be ignored.

UPD (explanation) :
Let's imagine I have following file structure:

```
-home
--some_dir
---file1
--another_dir
--dir_with_configs
---config.txt
```

And I am in `/home/dir_with_configs` directory.
Let `config.txt` be like:

```
/home/some_dir/file1
/home/some_dir/lol
```

After running

```bash
find . -type f | xargs sed -r -i "s/home\/some_dir/home\/another_dir/g"
```

I will have `config.txt` like:

```
/home/another_dir/file1
/home/another_dir/lol
```

But I don't have file `/home/another_dir/lol`. So I somehow want to add check that file with given path exists and have `config.txt` like:

```
/home/another_dir/file1
/home/some_dir/lol
```

Comment: If file home/some_dir/lol doesn't exist, it won't be returned by find?

Comment: BTW, `find . -type f | xargs ...` is buggy. **Always** use `find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 ...` -- otherwise filenames with spaces, literal quote characters, backslashes, &c will be mishandled. Or you can use `find ... -exec ... {} +` and not need xargs at all.

Comment: Do you want to check the original or target path? `/home/another_dir/file1` doesn't exist in your example, why did you replace it? Wat it because `/home/some_dir/file1` exists?

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you want to do the following on each file that you find.

1. Test that each line is an existing file
2. Test that each existing file also exists on an alternate path
3. If both are true, replace the line with the alternate path

`sed` can't do most of this. You need a different tool. Something like perl or python would probably be the most efficient choice. Either way, your program will have to actually read each line of the input file and test if that line represents a real file on your system before doing anything to it.

Here's a bash example that passes the files discovered by `find` into a small script that reads the lines from those files, tests them, and makes any necessary substitutions to the output.

```
find . -type f -exec /bin/bash -c '
  for file ; do
    while read -r line ; do
      if [[ -f "${line}" && -f "${line/some_dir/another_dir}" ]] ; then
        printf "%s\n" "${line/some_dir/another_dir}"
      else
        printf "%s\n" "${line}"
      fi
    done <"${file}" >"${file}.new" && mv "${file}.new" "${file}"
  done
' _ {} +
```